# Генератор полей формы на JS. Как улучшить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать простой генератор формы, где можно добавлять только input type="text" и textarea.

Сделал две кнопки, при нажатии на которые добавляются поля:

```
<input type="button" id="input" value="TextField" onclick="dynamic_field('text',1)" />
                <input type="button" id="textarea" value="TextArea" onclick="dynamic_field('textarea',2)" />
```

И такой JS код:

```
function dynamic_field(type,div_no){
            if(type == 'text'){
                document.getElementById('dynamic_field_'+div_no).innerHTML='TextField Name : <input type = "text" name="txt_field"> -> your text field has been generated just define name';    
            }else if (type == 'textarea'){
                document.getElementById('dynamic_field_'+div_no).innerHTML='TextArea Name : <input type = "text" name="text_area"> -> your text area has been generated just define name';  
            }else if (type == 'table_name'){
                document.getElementById('dynamic_field_'+div_no).innerHTML='Table Name : <input type = "text" name="table_name"> -> your table has been generated just define name';    
            }
        }
```

Как мне нужно изменить код, чтобы я при нажатии на кнопку 5 раз получил 5 полей формы? Сейчас каждая кнопка реагирует только на первое нажатие клавиши мышки.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не юзай `onClick` (за последнее время уже счёт потерял сколько я это говорю) - вредно это.
Во-вторых, ты **устанавливаешь** содержимое, а не **добавляешь**.
См. ниже:

```js
var el; // Сферический элемент в вакууме

el.innerHTML = '1';
el.innerHTML = '2';
// Содержимое el: 2

el.innerHTML = '1';
el.innerHTML += '2';
// Содержимое el: 12
```